# React-Redux - using a response from a fetch request in componentDidMount in another request in the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a component that fires off a fetch request (in redux) on componentDidMount.  In the same component I need to fire off another redux fetch request using the response data from the first one, preferably before the render.

Due to the fetch being executed in the redux action I havent been able to do this with a promise in componentDidMount as the promise resolves when the action starts and not finishes.

on research I thought it might be able to do it with componentWillRecieveProps however I don't fully understand how and also read that this hook is being depreciated soon.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

first action:

```
componentDidMount(){    
 this.props.onGetSessionId(this.parseToken(this.props.location.search))
};
```

secondAction:

```
this.props.onFetchFavourites(this.props.sessionId)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to help here without seeing the code for how `onGetSessionId` and `onFetchFavourites` are implemented but assuming that you're using [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk), it's probably something like this:

```
function getSessionId(token) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    return fetchSessionId(token)
    .then(
      response => dispatch(getSessionIdSuccess(forPerson, response.id))
    )
    .catch(
      error => dispatch(getSessionIdFailure(error)
    )
  };
}

function getFavorites(sessionId) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    return fetchFavorites(sessionId)
    .then(
      response => dispatch(getFavoritesSuccess(sessionId, response.favorites))
    )
    .catch(
      error => dispatch(getFavoritesFailure(error)
    )
  };
}
```

[fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) returns a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) so you can just keep chaining `.then` and using the return value from the previous `then`. this lets you do something like

```
function getSessionIdAndFavorites(token) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    return fetchSessionId()
    .then(
      response => {
        dispatch(getSessionIdSuccess(response.id))
        return response.id
      }
    )
    .then(id => {dispatch(getFavorites(id)}
    .catch(
      error => dispatch(getSessionAndFavoritesIdFailure(error)
    )
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `onGetSessionId` you can return promise, like this:

```
function onGetSessionId(param) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        apiClient.call()
            .then(data => {
                resolve(data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                reject(error)
            })
    })
}
```

and then in `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.props.onGetSessionId(this.parseToken(this.props.location.search))
        .then(data => {
            // ... do stuff with returned data
        })
}
```